# How can i test on readonly input with zombie.js and node.js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, zombie.js

I would like to to a browser.assert in my mocha tests with zombie.js.

How can i select / test the readonly flag for the bootstrap input field (i use jade) 

`input.form-control(name="OSMUser",id="OSMUser",value = "test" readonly)`

Zombie.js does ignore the flag (so i can fill the textfield, while it should be readonly), so i assume, i have to test that the flag is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out what to do.

The JADE Code for the form was:

`input.form-control(name="OSMUser",id="OSMUser",value = "test" readonly)`

This is generated to the following HTML

`<input name="OSMUser" id="OSMUser" value="TheFive" readonly="readonly" class="form-control">`

To find out the existence of this input field I have to use the following node.js Code based on zombie.js

`browser.assert.text('input[readonly="readonly"][name="OSMUser"]');`